# Array 11th index

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Ok so I was reworking the current infrastructure for my AI and I created it into an array. But i'm not sure how to get the 11th value to be recognized in the array "dictonary"

Here is the code!

```
string name = "Jarvis";
string[] dictionary = new string[] { "hello", "how", "are", "you", "sup", "wake", "up", "daddys", "home", "what", "version", "whats", "your" };

bool helloflag = false;
void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    string code = "";
    //ResultText = "Hello how are you"
    string[] words = e.Result.Text.Split(' ');
    //words = ["Hello", "how", "are", "you"]
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < dictionary.Count(); index++)
        {
            if (word == dictionary[index])
            {
                code += index.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    //code = "123"; //how are you
    //code = "236"; //are you up

    //HELLO
    if ((code == "0") || (code == "4"))
    {
        Jarvis.Speak("Hello sir");
        helloflag = true;
    } else if ((helloflag == true ) && (code == "123"))
    {
        Jarvis.Speak("im good sir");
        helloflag = false;
    }
```

This is part of the .NET speech API, but is using an array to call the words you say.

Comment: Please stop tagging these questions with `AI`. It's like tagging the question "Do you write 'a hamburger' or 'an hamburger'?" with `food` or `literature`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're adding to `code`, you need to put a separator between the codes. Otherwise, you can't tell whether `12` is word 1 followed by word 2, or word 12. E.g.

```
code += index.toString() + " ";
```

Then you can do things like:

```
if (code == "10 9 2 3 ") // whats version are you
```

**Don't forget the space at the end.**

Comment: so how would I order an array index bigger than 11, like this "          if ((code == "09100203")) or if ((code == "09 10 02 03"))?

Comment: I added the space and everything ordered it all like what you did, and it still dosen't work, my dad said something about him not setting the code to be an index past 11 elements... I understand what your saying but not where I can make the index larger...

Comment: What's so special about 11?

Comment: The mind boggles at someone who is attempting to program AI, but is having a problem with basic data structures. Shouldn't you learn programming basics before tackling a problem that gives the most accomplished programmers trouble?

Comment: nothing but the next index being 12 then 13, and I cant get past 10, all of the first 10 index commands work just not 11+

Comment: ya I had the entire thing if statments, and it all worked fine, but this is a step up in speed of the program and everything else, and I somewhat know the basics from one python class and just taught myself the rest...

Comment: My code treats all indexes the same, whether they're 1 or 2 digits.

Comment: So those 2 things you listed up top were all I had to change in my code?

Comment: I think that's all you need.

Comment: @JoeMeyer what didn't work? Barmars answer is pretty clear. instead of storing only the digits in the string (btw there are better ways to store informations, like lists or other collections) he stores the hole number and every number is seperated by a whitespace

Comment: @MartinHoratschek for some reason it just didnt go off, and actaully broke all the code.

Comment: @JoeMeyer if you want help you need to lern to be more specific. what error did the compiler give you?

Answer (score 1):

Prob it is more flexible to store your code values in array, e.g.:

```
var code = new List<int>();
....
code.Add(index);
...
if(code.SequenceEqual(new int[] {1, 2, 3})
{
...
```